# ionic serve external disappeared

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

My 'ionic serve' didn't provide 'external url' any more.
Just can access 'local(localhost:8100)'.
both of Ionic3 and Ionic4 have same problem.

```
$ ionic serve
```

then

```
[INFO] Development server running!

       Local: http://localhost:8100

       Use Ctrl+C to quit this process

[INFO] Browser window opened to http://localhost:8100!
```

I want this result. (External url)

```
[INFO] Development server running!

       Local: http://localhost:8100

       External: http://172.30.5.17:8100

       Use Ctrl+C to quit this process

[INFO] Browser window opened to http://localhost:8100!
```

Comment: Might be an issue with the firewall settings. If you are under any firewall, Ionic will not generate the external URL

Comment: Sadly no. I'm using mac OS. I checked 'setting => firewall'. And firewall is already offed. I'm so sad.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then you can install ngrok on your Mac to make your localhost deployment available on a public url more or less like https://yourapp.ngrok.com

Answer (score 1):

Just `ionic serve --external` :)